# DNN Module - Linked Files

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have created a DNN module using the Visual Studio template. I have the same module that works with several DNN carts. When I make changes in the core project, I want those changes to appear in the projects beneath it:

Core
  ReleaseNotes.txt

Smith Cart
  ReleaseNotes.txt (linked file)

Revindex
  ReleaseNotes.txt (linked file)

I added the file by right clicking add existing item > add > linked file. When I try to install a module with the linked file, I receive an error that the ReleaseNotes.txt cannot be found.

Can I not use linked files in a DNN module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using my templates? (http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com) If so, you will likely need to modify the modulepackage.targets file to handle retrieval of the linked files. It is likely that the build script process doesn't know anything about the linked file and can't find it for packing.

I've not dealt with Linked Files before, so I really don't know what all will be involved.

**Updated**:
You might check out the last reply to this post on adding a new target
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/6115f496-9e63-43e9-8642-2e0b3f413429/

Comment: Hi, yes I am using that template. Does anyone know how to edit the modulepackage targets file to handle the linked files?

Comment: My guess is that you might need to tell the modulepackage.targets file the specific hard coded path to the original file.